# /usr/bin/env: «node\r» "no such file" error using JS Best Practices

Tags: ubuntu-16.04

Im trying to use js best practices, i use js-best-practices then the error /usr/bin/env: «node\r» "no such file" appear and the program don't run
I appreciate any solution you put. Thanks

Comment: Did you edit this file on Windows, perhaps?  The problem is that the file has Windows line endings (carriage return + linefeed) rather than Unix (linefeed only).

Answer (score 2):

Looks like your script file has been created on Windows, the file is DOS format (line endings in DOS). So, you may use a module which converts a file to a Unix format :

```
brew install dos2unix
sudo dos2unix your_script
```

or use `tr` command to remove `\r` from your file:

```
cat your_script.js | tr -d '\r' > fixed_script.js
```

P.S. You can also use vim to convert Windows-style to Unix-style:

```
vim script

:se ff=unix
:wq
```